# Deploying a .NET application to AppHarbor that doesn't use ASP

Tags: c#, .net, appharbor

I have a desktop application idea that requires a server component to work. Unfortunately, I'm very new to web programming so I don't really know how everything works.

What I do know is that I don't need a website. The server I'm gonna be making doesn't output any HTML. It just needs to do some simple database access and a few checks here and there.

In this case, I'm assuming ASP.NET is an overkill and I haven't worked with ASP anyways, so I'm wondering is I can just push a console application to AppHarbor. If I can, how do I manage requests (or how do I actually send requests to it when it's deployed)? If I can't do that, I'm willing to use something else (Heroku with Ruby maybe) that would allow me to do that.
I'd use Ruby in the first place but the very same question remains. Just RoR instead of ASP.NET.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple ASP.NET project for hosting WCF. In Visual studio click File->New->Web Site.

In your desktop application add reference to this WCF service (Right click on project Add Service Reference and then past URL, which you can see after running WCF service)

Comment: As I said, I don't really understand how the whole thing works. Do I deploy the desktop application to? Do they have to be projects in the same solution? Is there any way to separate those two?

Comment: Also, is there a way to do wthis with Visual C# Express or do I need the Web dev version?

Comment: You need a Web version also. You can only deploy there a web application. The desktop on you have to deploy to your customers

Answer (score 0):

So, you can accomplish pretty easy with ASP.net WEBApi calls; however, this is what I would do if I did not want to use ASP.net for anything.

1. Create a Windows WCF Service. This is basically a service that does exactly what your looking for, takes requests over the internet and sends the serialized data back. You can find a tutorial [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx).
2. Host the WCF service somewhere. I'm a big fan of Azure, but there are many places you can do this.
3. Create you application that you would like to pull data from this service. To set yourself up to pull data from this service, right click on the project and select, "Add Service Reference". Once you do this, you'll be able to use the methods exposed by the service as if it was a class in your project.